# How do I get notified on a failed deployment to azure?

Tags: azure, github

I have a project hosted in Github that is being continuously deployed to Azure whenever a developer checks in any code. (this deployment is for a dev server, not prod).

In the case of a failed deployment, how can I get the failure log emailed to me automatically? This does not seem to be a current feature in Azure.

For the deployment, we are using a Kudu deploy.cmd file generated with the

```
azure site deploymentscript
```

command. In this script there are several tests for errors after the commands finish. Such as:

```
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
```

with the error label executing these commands:

```
:error
endlocal
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul
```

It seems to me that this would be an ideal place to have the log file emailed to me. But I am not sure what that would look like. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently Kudu has a web interface I was previously unaware of. If you browse to:

```
https://{mysitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net
```

you get dropped into Kudu's admin site. From here you can do a lot of things. One of them being browsing through a list of plugins that people have written for Kudu!

Sadly, none of them seemingly will send you an email on a failed deployment.

However, one of the other things you can do is wire up "webhooks". This is a callback url where Kudu will notify after any deployment.

So the long answer to the question is: create another website that will listen for these notifications from Kudu. Have the code of that website use the Kudu API to get the deployment log file if there is a failure. Have the code of the website then email that log file.

Seems like a lot of steps, but there is no reason it won't work.

Comment: Apparently, it has been done here https://github.com/WCOMAB/KuduPostDeploymentSlackHook already